# connected dots with pandas visualization

Tags: pandas, plot

I have a pandas DataFrame object stored in df that has 2 columns (Capital (in Euro) and percent (in %)). The indices are years from 0-30.

I want to plot the yearly total capital and the percent value for each year in one plot.

So I used:

```
df.plot(subplots=True)
```

The plot is good but I think it would be better if there are also dots for each value. Can you tell me if this is possible with pandas visualization? I found examples how to do it with plt but I thought this also must be possible with pandas.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
df.plot(subplots=True, marker = 'o')
```

Comment: ...Thanks Noobie. I did try 'linestyle' and because this caused an error I thought 'marker' wouldn't work either.